# 数値を文字に変換する方法がわからない

Tags: python

画像の通り出力してみたのですがうまくいきません。やはりif,elif 以降がダメそうです。解決策をお願いします。じゃんけんのプログラミングです。[image: 現状]

[image: このように出力したい]

Comment: 何を指して上手くいっていないとお思いなのでしょうか？張られた画像を見る限り、まったく問題ないように見えます。

Comment: もしかすると`dct = {0:'グー', 1:'チョキ', 2:'パー'};` `print(dct[num])` という話？

Answer (score 1):

自分は下記を参考して、
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968112/how-to-give-jupyter-cell-standard-input-in-python

inputのあとにprintを入れて実行できました。そちらのコードは全然問題なかった。

```
import random
comp = random.randint(0,2)
n = int(input("手を選んでください"))
print(n)
# ここ一旦Cell切り分け
```